# Execute a function after the url changes in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I would like to know if it's possible to use .unload(...) or a similar function in Javascript or jQuery in order to execute an action **after** the user changes or reload the page.

In my specific case, I've done a bookmarklet which creates a div element on the page and I want to keep it during my navigation, without executing another time the Javascript code.

I thought to solve it using JS/jQuery because I would not depend from my browser. If it's not possible, how can I achieve a similar result?

Answer (score 1):

A URL change stops all current JavaScript execution.

You may want to look into using [a URL HASH to maintain state](https://developers.google.com/tv/web/articles/location-hash-navigation#loc-hash).

Comment: Thank you, this is an interesting thing, but it depends on how the website is made, so I can't use it in my case (my problem is focused on the client).

Comment: Yes, you can use it. When your page relods, you look for the hash in the URL, then re-initialize the UI elements. It's all about the client. You don't even need a server for this technique.

Comment: Sorry, but when the page is reloaded, the script injected is already gone (I'm creating a bookmarklet). When I said "focused on the client" I meant that I can't edit the website. Maybe I'm missing something.